# Imprimir recibos usando impresora térmica

Tags: c#, windows-forms, impresión

**Transfondo:**

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en C# de tipo [windows-forms](/questions/tagged/windows-forms) que ejecuta los siguientes pasos:

- Leer texto pre-configurado en un archivo de recursos *(.resx)*.
- Formatear el texto obtenido del paso anterior con valores proporcionados en el formulario. *(nombres, apellidos, y fecha actual).*
- Guardar la información diligenciada en base de datos SQL.
- Usando una [impresora térmica ON 500](http://www.tecnologiasciws.com/new/producto/IMPRESORA-TERMICA-ON-500)<sup>1</sup>, generar dos impresiones de la información diligenciada.

**Problema**

Al momento de imprimir, **la impresora térmica no corta los informes** (es decir, no divide los recibos/impresiones generadas), lo cual genera desperdicio de papel.

El código que estoy usando para leer el texto pre-configurado hasta la invocación del método *`Print();`* es:

```
// Imprimir recibo #1:
PrintDocument document_member1 = new PrintDocument();
document_member1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(document_PrintPage_Member1);
document_member1.Print();

// Imprimir recibo #2:
PrintDocument document_member2 = new PrintDocument();
document_member2.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(document_PrintPage_Member2);
document_member2.Print();
```

Mis inquietudes son:

- ¿Cómo enviar el comando o la instrucción a la impresora términa para cortar luego de generar cada impresión?
- ¿Cómo definir el tamaño de cada impresión?.
- ¿Existe una mejor alternativa a usar `PrintDocument` para realizar esta funcionalidad?

Ejemplo de tamaños de las impresiones a realizar:

1. Recibo #1: 360px X 360px
2. Recibo #2: 360px X 560px

---

<sup>1</sup> Es la marca de la impresora que me asignaron para las pruebas y probablemente sea la impresora estándar del cliente; pero si hay información para "desde C# de alguna manera interactuar con el driver de la impresora" esa solución también sería válida.

He buscado términos como:

- C# POS receipt printing
- POS printing in C#

Pero esto es muy nuevo para mí y estoy completamente perdido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En algún momento un compañero tenia este problema, lo resolvio usando [RawPrinterHelper](https://github.com/andyyou/SendToPrinter/blob/master/Printer/RawPrinterHelper.cs) que es un pequeño util que alguien desarrollo.

Con el metodo `SendStringToPrinter` se manda el comando de corte.

Buscando en internet el comando encontre lo siguiente:

> ```
> string GS = Convert.ToString((char)29);
>                     string ESC = Convert.ToString((char)27);
>                     string COMMAND = "";
>                     COMMAND = ESC + "@";
>                     COMMAND += GS + "V" + (char)1;
>                     RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, COMMAND);
> ```
>
> De [How to send cut command in Thermal Printer](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/534127/HowplustoplussendpluscutpluscommandplusinplusTherm)

Y

> `sendStringtoprinter( CHR$(27) & CHR$(100); & CHR$(51))` en [Send Cut Command to POS printer](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21138620/Send-Cut-Command-to-POS-printer.html)

Y es que no recuerdo cual es el comando exacto, ademas no estoy seguro si varié entre modelos.

Quiza si buscas el comando para el modelo que tienes lo puedas encontrar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, había visto `RawPrinterHelper` pero no lo había probado, no ví donde era el corte. Con tu respuesta he logrado el 90%. Ahora me falta mejorar el tamaño de cada recibo o el corte: El corte lo hace, pero no completo (queda pegado por un punto en la mitad del ticket).